# removing rows with given criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I am beginer with both python and pandas and I came across an issue I can't handle on my own. 
What I am trying to do is:
1) remove all the columns except three that I am interested in
2) remove all rows which contains serveral strings in column "asset number". And here is difficult part. I removed all the blanks but I can't remove other ones because nothing happens (example with string "TECHNOLOGIES" - tried part of the word and whole word and both don't work.

Here is the code:

```
import modin.pandas as pd


File1 = 'abi.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(File1, sheet_name = 'US JERL Dec-19')


df = df[['asset number','Cost','accumulated depr']] #removing other columns


df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace = False)
```

df =  df[~df['asset number'].str.contains("TECHNOLOGIES, INC", na=False)]

```
df.to_excel("abi_output.xlsx")
```

And besides that, file has 600k rows and it loads so slow to see the output. Do you have any advice for it?

Thank you!

@Kenan - thank you for your answer. Now the code looks like below but it still doesn't remove rows which contains in chosen column specified stirngs. I also attached screenshot of the output to show you that the rows still exist. Any thoughts?

```
import modin.pandas as pd


File1 = 'abi.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(File1, sheet_name = 'US JERL Dec-19', usecols=['asset number','Cost','accumulated depr'])


several_strings = ['', 'TECHNOLOGIES', 'COST CENTER', 'Account', '/16']

df = df[~df['asset number'].isin(several_strings)]


df.to_excel("abi_output.xlsx")
```

[rows still are not deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6icA.jpg) 
@Andy
I attach sample of the input file. I just changed the numbers in two columns because these are confidential and removed not needed columns (removing them with code wasn't a problem).

Here is the link. Let me know if this is not working properly. 
[enter link description here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqTGjOBznBqagSlOztfL19eetcLK?e=09HMPR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your first two steps with:

`df = pd.read_excel(File1, sheet_name = 'US JERL Dec-19', usecols=['asset number','Cost','accumulated depr'])`

I assume this is what your trying to remove
`several_strings = ['TECHNOLOGIES, INC','blah','blah']`

```
df = df[~df['asset number'].isin(several_string)]
df.to_excel("abi_output.xlsx")
```

**Update**
Based on the link you provided this might be a better approach

`df = df[df['asset number'].str.len().eq(7)]`

Comment: I applied the changes to my code. It is still not working idk why - there is no any error or something but rows are still there. Could you kindly look at my edited first post once again? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the code your given is correct. so I guess maybe there is something wrong with your strings in columns 'asset number', can you give some examples for a code check?

Comment: I added link at the bottom of first post. Thanks!